# Create a jQuery List from Model Property Without Razor

Tags: jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I have a form where clients can fill out a minimum of 1 people (the primary client) or up to 8 (1 primary, 7 dependent). I am creating this form using razor syntax, and it works and is passing just fine. When client's click a button (not shown here), it will add another one of these to the form (so you would see two of these forms instead of just one.

[image: Form chunk that is being replicated]

This is being handled by jQuery (see AddDiver function). jQuery is literally just adding HTML to the page and changing the name of it. So if Client[ 0 ].FirstName already exists, it will add Client[ 1 ].FirstName, and so on.

This part works fine.

The issue I am having is with the select dropdown. The drop-down is being populated with products from the database every time the page is loaded, so the clients can see the most up-to-date products and pricing. The first select box, the one written in razor, works fine.

**Main Question:** How do you take a list of products (see ProductNames in the model) and create a jQuery generated dropdown based on it.

When I try to put razor syntax into jQuery, it just populates as text on the page, rather than turning into a dropdown, so I'm guessing it will need to be in HTML format, not razor syntax. But I'm not sure how to do this since the options may change each time the page loads (so I don't want to hard code options into my .js file.

```
public class InvoiceDiverAdd
{
    public Client Client { get; set; } 
    public List<Client> Clients { get; set; } 
    public List<ProductCommon> Products { get; set; } 
    public List<SelectListItem> ProductNames { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
 }
```

---

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Product, Model.ProductNames, new { @class = "form-control", Name = "Clients[0].ProductName", id = "Clients[0].ProductName" })
```

---

```
function addDiver(idNumber){
   var newDiver = "<div class='row form-group col-xl-12'>";
   newDiver += "<label for='name' class='col-4'>Full Name</label>";
   newDiver += "<input type='text' class='col-4 form-control' name='Clients[" + idNumber + "].FirstName', placeholder='First Name'/>";
   newDiver += "<input type='text' class='col-4 form-control' name='Clients[" + idNumber + "].LastName', placeholder='Last Name'/>";
   newDiver += "</div>";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to put the products in a global JavaScript variable on page load.

In your view.cshtml add:

```
<script>
   _productNames = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.ProductNames))')
   // I suggest using the Newtonsoft serializer if you can
   // _productNames = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ProductNames))')
</script>
```

Then loop through the variable in your `addDriver` function:

```
function addDiver(idNumber){
   var newDiver = "<div class='row form-group col-xl-12'>";
   newDiver += "<label for='name' class='col-4'>Full Name</label>";
   newDiver += "<input type='text' class='col-4 form-control' name='Clients[" + idNumber + "].FirstName', placeholder='First Name'/>";
   newDiver += "<input type='text' class='col-4 form-control' name='Clients[" + idNumber + "].LastName', placeholder='Last Name'/>";
   newDiver += "<select class='form-control' name='Clients[" + idNumber + "].ProductName' id='Clients[" + idNumber + "].ProductName'>";
   $(_productNames).each(function() {
      newDiver += "<option value='" + this.Value + "'>" + this.Text + "</option>";
   });
   newDiver += "</select>";
   newDiver += "</div>";
}
```